# Can I use BlockingCollection for a network packet caching system?

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming, blockingcollection

I'm trying to implement a packet producer-consumer behavior by using a BlockingCollection, but I am having trouble understanding the documentation on it. From what I can tell, since apparently there is no guarantee that I can remove anything at all, the system would be too slow to be useful for performance-critical things like receiving and processing packets. The reason I need this is because the thread that receives packets is not the same thread that processes them. Am I missing something, or do I need to take another approach?

Example Code:

```
public BlockingCollection<byte[]> unprocessedPackets = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

public void Producer()
{
...Recieve packets...
    unprocessedPackets.Add(packet);
}

public void Consumer(){
    while(true) 
    {
        byte[] packet = unprocessedPackets.Take();
        ...If i took something, process it.
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `BlockingCollection<T>` works. If and when taking an element from the collection blocks, it's because there's nothing to take. The only "slowness" is in the I/O producing items for the collection.

Note that you can pass a timeout value to the `TryTake()` method, which will cause it to wait that length of time before giving up. But if you use the `TryTake(out T item)` overload (i.e. the one without a timeout), it will return immediately if there's nothing to take.

More typical would be a consumer thread that does nothing but retrieve items for processing. In this case, the `Take()` method or the `GetConsumingEnumerable()` method are more appropriate. Both will block indefinitely until there's an item available to take. I prefer the latter; it provides a very nice, usable mechanism both for consuming the collection, and for terminating the consumer when you know there's nothing left (i.e. the `CompleteAdding()` method is called by the producing code).